# Must the int main() function return a value in all compilers?

Tags: c++, turbo-c++

Why is it not necessary to include the return statement while using int main() in some compilers for C++? What about Turbo C++?

Comment: AFAIK, Turbo forces `void main` (which is invalid C++) and returns 0 for you.

Comment: I'm pretty certain that Turbo C++ conforms to exactly zero of the C++ standards in existence. As far as I'm aware, development of Turbo C++ had stopped at the time of 1998 when the first C++ standard was produced.

Comment: I hope you're asking out of historical curiosity, and not because you're planning to use a twenty-year-old compiler for anything.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

In C++, and in C99 and C11, it is a special rule of the language that if the control flow reaches the end of the `main` function, then the function impliclty returns `0`.

Comment: @H2CO3 how is it horrible?

Comment: @H2CO3 no it's not

Comment: @Kolyunya Almost as horrible as `void main()`.

Comment: Maybe because not enough people know about it, but other than that, I don't see much of a reason.

Comment: @NoIdeaForName Well, I hate when one lets the function fall off. Whoever relies on this in `main()` will do the same in other functions.

Comment: @H2CO3 I don't think that's generally true. Besides, in the vast majority of other situations the compiler will complain about it anyway.

Comment: @H2CO3 "Whoever relies on this in main() will do the same in other functions." Definitely not! I could argue it the other way: whoever returns `0` needlessly is likely to be lacking a clue, so they would be likely to fall off the end of a function. They probably write functions that are 500 lines long too :)

Comment: It's a matter of opinion, but I'm with @H2CO3 here. IMO this exception to the usual rules is totally unwarranted, and as any useless rule I find it a pain more than anything else.

Comment: @juanchopanza Well, you definitely haven't worked with the code of those people that I have, it seems. Oh, and I always `return 0;` at the end of `main()`. (Yeah, you'll now tell me that I'm lacking a clue...)

Comment: IMO you really should not rely on this; many compilers will issue a warning if you don't return anything from a non-void function, and I really like to compile with `-Wall -Werror` flags, so compilation will fail because of this useless exception...

Comment: Let's face reality. return from main() mostly has a meaning then application intended to be run from batches/scripts/whatever else which rely on return code. People who write such application/utilities are aware of that and I don't think there is an issue about that, but who on the Earth care which return code I get from Microsoft Word or Visual Studio.. Ok, I know and I agree that it's a good code practice, but I don't think it's most worst thing you can do..

Comment: @nijansen, Any compiler that refuses to compile not returning something from `main` can't be very good...

Comment: @evilruff What you say makes sense, but I'd rather allow `void main()` (and have the runtime "convert" it to `int main()` returning 0) rather than having this weird exception to the return rules. But maybe that's just me.

Comment: Looking back, it's not even about C/C++ or whatever language. it's an OS convention have an ability to retrieve a return code for whatever purpose it needs it.. somebody still remember 4Ch function of interrupt 21h? I think main() function as any entry point place itself is a pretty 'exceptional' (take WinMain() for example..) sometimes it's just forgotten that our programs exist in real world and standards still should rely on real things, haven't being a 'spherical horse in space'.. i.e. DLL which also a software in a way, but has completely different rules for loading/entry points etc..

Comment: What I am saying is that 'return code' for main() in a way out of the scope for language itself..its about about compiler for specific environment to decide what to do with that..  that's why main() is exceptional and i don't see really issues with 'special cases'.

Comment: @H2CO3 `main` is not like any other function anyway (it must return and `int` and has at least two possible parameter-list signatures but you can't overload it, you can't explicitly call it from code, you can't take its address...) and every "decent" C++ programmer should know (or learn) that it is special. (Now, "real" code often returns an error code (nonzero) from `main` in case of failure, so then it's just "natural" to explicitly return zero in case of non-failure.)

Comment: I don't have my K&R in front of me, but I don't think they returned 0 from every main() they wrote.  So worst case, it's some kind of deprecated behavior that should still be supported.

Comment: I agree that it's horrible. The compiler has to have special hack behaviors for compiling the internals of `main` just for the sake of sloppy programmers. Other `int`-returning functions will not return `0` if control reaches their end and there is no return statement.  So, the rule should apply to all functions, or to no functions at all.

Comment: @Kaz main already is center of a lot of "hacks" that make it the official entry point of a program, adding a rule that the default exit state of a program is success instead of requiring unnecessary verboseness is not any more horrible. (main does not even qualify as function - you are not allowed to call it yourself)

Comment: @josefx You can call main in C, but not in C++.  So that is just another horrible hack, albeit specific to C++.

Answer (score 26):

In C++ and C99/C11, without a return statement in main function, it's **default to return 0**;

§ 3.6.1 Main function

> A return statement in main has the effect of leaving the main function (destroying any objects with automatic storage duration) and calling std::exit with the return value as the argument. If control reaches the end of main without encountering a return statement, the effect is that of executing return 0;

also read wiki page  [C/C++ main function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_function#C_and_C.2B.2B)

> In case a return value is not defined by the programmer, an implicit return 0; at the end of the main() function is inserted by the compiler; this behavior is required by the C++ standard.

Comment: A small mistake: for C, this is not the case in C89, only C99 and C11 support it.

Answer (score 13):

`main` must return an `int`, some compilers, including Turbo C++, may allow other return values, notably `void main`, but it's wrong, never use that.

However in C++, if you don't explicitly return a value in `main`, it's the same as `return 0;`

> **C++11 §3.6.1 Main function** section 5
>
> A return statement in main has the effect of leaving the main function (destroying any objects with automatic storage duration) and calling std::exit with the return value as the argument. If control reaches the end of main without encountering a return statement, the effect is that of executing
>
> ```
> return 0;
> ```

Note that for C, this is only supported in C99 and later, but not supported by C89.

Answer (score 4):

The standard says that `main` will return `0` if there is no `return` statement. From the [draft C++ standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3485.pdf) section `3.6.1` paragraph `5`:

> return statement in main has the effect of leaving the main function (destroying any objects with automatic storage duration) and calling std::exit with the return value as the argument. **If control reaches the end of main without encountering a return statement, the effect is that of executing**
>
> ```
>    return 0;
> ```

The `C99` draft standard in section `5.1.2.2.3` says:

> If the return type of the main function is a type compatible with int, a return from the
> initial call to the main function is equivalent to calling the exit function with the value
> returned by the main function as its argument;10) **reaching the } that terminates the
> main function returns a value of 0.**

From what I can tell the last version of [Turbo C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turbo_C%2B%2B) is quite old and I can not find anything that defines which standard if any it supports.

Answer (score 1):

TC will return EXIT_SUCCESS no matter you explicit specify or not

Answer (score 0):

Other than conforming to an arbitrary language standard, there is no compelling reason to return a value when the main function ends.

It is only because processes on the popular operating systems have a notion of a return code for a process that has terminated. It is not hard to imagine an operating system where they need not return any value. You can also imagine a world where 0 is implicitly returned by all processes unless otherwise overridden -- in which case, you can delegate the return code decision to a system call. (In fact, such a system call already exists in the form of C's exit function).

Answer (score 0):

As other people have stated, some compilers don't require you to explicitly `return 0;` however, it is always a good idea to (if possible). I would discourage the use of any compiler that disallows you from returning from your main function.

I would like to note that the return value from int main is very important, and actually has a use.

The return value from main is sometimes referred to as the `exit status` or `error code` from your program, zero indicating that it completed successfully. Other programs and scripts can access this code to determine if your program completed successfully.

More information here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_status