# Reversibly Combining Two uint32_t's Without Changing Datatype

Tags: c++, integer, encryption, uint32-t

Here's my issue:  I need to pass back two uint32_t's via a single uint32_t (because of how the API is set up...).  I can hard code whatever other values I need to reverse the operation, but the parameter passed between functions needs to stay a single uint32_t.

This would be trivial if I could just bit-shift the two 32-bit ints into a single 64-bit int (like what was explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2768890/how-to-combine-two-32-bit-integers-into-one-64-bit-integer)), but the compiler wouldn't like that.  I've also seen mathematical [pairing functions](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PairingFunction.html), but I'm not sure if that's what I need in this case.

I've thought of setting up a simple cipher: the unint32_t could be the cipher text, and I could just hard code the key.  This is an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19646977/caesar-cipher-program-in-c), but that seems like overkill.

Is this even possible?

Comment: What range of values does each `uint32_t` need to represent?  At one extreme, do they need the full range of 4 billion or, at the other, are they both representing bools?

Comment: In most cases, the numbers would be < 1,000.  I'm reluctant to just shift the low-order bits of both into a single uint32_t, but that would work in the short term.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on how much trouble this is really worth, you could:

1. create a global array or `vector` of `std::pair<uint32_t,uint32_t>`
2. pass an index into the function, then your "reverse" function just looks up the result in the array.
3. write some code to decide which index to use when you have a pair to pass. The index needs to not be in use by anyone else, and since the array is global there may be thread-safety issues. Essentially what you are writing is a simple memory allocator.

As a special case, on a machine with 32 bit data pointers you could allocate the struct and `reinterpret_cast` the pointer to and from `uint32_t`. So you don't need any globals.

Beware that you need to know whether or not the function you pass the value into might store the value somewhere to be "decoded" later, in which case you have a more difficult resource-management problem than if the function is certain to have finished using it by the time it returns.

In the easy case, and if the code you're writing doesn't need to be re-entrant at all, then you only need to use one index at a time. That means you don't need an array, just one `pair`. You could pass `0` to the function regardless of the values, and have the decoder ignore its input and look in the global location.

If both special cases apply (32 bit and no retaining of the value), then you can put the `pair` on the stack, and use no globals and no dynamic allocation even if your code does need to be re-entrant.

None of this is really recommended, but it could solve the problem you have.

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible to store more than 32 bits of information using only 32 bits. This is a basic result of information theory.

If you know that you're only using the low-order 16 bits of each value, you could shift one left 16 bits and combine them that way. But there's absolutely no way to get 64 bits worth of information (or even 33 bits) into 32 bits, period.

Comment: Correct, but it's not simply 32-bits, though.  What has to be passed as a parameter is 32-bits, but I have whatever other data I need present in the receiving function.

Comment: @Chance I don't see how that matters. Only 32 bits of information is being transferred from the function to the caller. You can't get around that without changing the return type (or using a global variable or passing in an argument where the function can store information or something).

Answer (score 1):

You can use an intermediate global data structure to store the pair of `uint32_t` on it, using your only `uint32_t` parameter as the index on the structure:

```
struct my_pair {
  uint32_t a, b;
};

std::map<uint32_t, my_pair> global_pair_map;

uint32_t register_new_pair(uint32_t a, uint32_t b) {
  // Add the pair of (a, b) to the map global_pair_map on a new key, and return the
  // new key value.
}

void release_pair(uint32_t key) {
  // Remove the key from the global_pair_map.
}

void callback(uint32_t user_data) {
  my_pair& p = global_pair_map[user_data];

  // Use your pair of uint32_t with p.a, and p.b.
}

void main() {
  uint32_t key = register_new_pair(number1, number2);

  register_callback(callback, key);
}
```