# Function must return a value

Tags: c++

I am trying to make a text based RPG and i'm fairly new to c++. I understand that I need to return a value, but when I try and return CharacterName or CharacterRace it comes up with unresolved externals errors. I'd really appreciate the help guys, thanks :)

CharacterCreation.h

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

void petc(), ConsoleClear(), petc(), EnterClear();

std::string CharacterName, CharacterRace;
```

Main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <string>
#include <string.h>
#include "CharacterCreation.h"

std::string CharacterCreation();


int main()
{
    CharacterCreation();

}



std::string CharacterCreation(int RaceChoice, int RaceChoiceLoop)
{

RaceChoiceLoop = 0;
std::cout << "Welcome to the character creation V 1.0.0" << std::endl;
EnterClear();
std::cout << "Choose a name: ";
std::cin >> CharacterName;
std::cout << CharacterName << std::endl;

EnterClear();

while (RaceChoiceLoop == 0)
{

    std::cout << "(1) Human - Human's race perks: + 5 to Magic | + 1 to         Sword Skill" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "(2) Elf - Elve's race perks: + 5 to Archery | + 1 to Magic" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "(3) Dwarf - Dwarven race perks: + 5 to Strength | + 1 to Archery" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Choose a race, " << CharacterName << ": ";
    std::cin >> RaceChoice;

    if (RaceChoice == 1)
    {
        RaceChoiceLoop = 1;
        CharacterRace = "Human";
    }

    else if (RaceChoice == 2)
    {
        RaceChoiceLoop = 1;
        CharacterRace = "Elf";
    }

    else if (RaceChoice == 3)
    {
        RaceChoiceLoop = 1;
        CharacterRace = "Dwarf";
    }

    else
    {
        std::cout << "Invalid Option";
        EnterClear();
        RaceChoiceLoop = 0;

    }

}






}



void petc()
{
    std::cout << "Press Enter To Continue...";
    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
}




void EnterClear()
{
    std::cout << "Press Enter To Continue...";
    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    system("cls");

}



void ConsoleClear()
{
    system("cls");
}
```

Comment: don't forget a return in `main`

Comment: @NendoTaka NO. You don't need a return in `main`, unless you want to return a non-zero status.

Comment: @vsoftco Yes you *do* need a return value, even if its zero.

Comment: @YSC In C, yes. In C++, no.

Comment: @molbdnilo Look at the tag of this question.

Comment: @vsoftco it is not required but is good practice

Comment: @YSC `0` is implicitly returned from `main` in C++ if there is no return statement.

Comment: isnt there lacking return in CharacterCreation method?

Comment: Also in C99 and C11. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18402853/must-the-int-main-function-return-a-value-in-all-compilers

Comment: @Lil Jakers.. welcome to the world of disagreement

Comment: What is the exact error that you are getting @Lil Jakers

Comment: what is the error anyway?

Comment: My bad. I didn't know before today. I'll keep returning though.

Comment: Error 1 error C4716: 'CharacterCreation' : must return a value c:\users\jake\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\characterselection\characterselection\main.cpp 72 1 CharacterSelection @mikus

Comment: so this is the answer, if you define string as a return value of a method you must return a string at one point :), just as i mentioned in a comment abover

Comment: I resolved it guys, I needed to use RaceChoice and RaceChoiceLoop as local variables instead I made them parameters. Lesson learned thats fot taking the time to help me out everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "unresolved externals" message isn't directly caused by your returning a value.
It's a linker error, and only occurs because compilation succeeded.

The cause is that you're declaring, and calling, this parameter-less function:

```
std::string CharacterCreation();
```

but you're defining this function with two parameters:

```
std::string CharacterCreation(int RaceChoice, int RaceChoiceLoop)
```

The declaration and the definition must match.

From the looks of it, you don't actually want the parameters and should use local variables instead:

```
std::string CharacterCreation()
{
    int RaceChoice = 0;
    int RaceChoiceLoop = 0;
    // ...
```

Comment: Thank you so much, you were right I needed to make them local variables not parameters, lesson learn thank you very much for taking the time to help me out.

Comment: in the meanwhile the errors is:
Error 1 error C4716: 'CharacterCreation' : must return a value c:\users\jake\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\characterselection\characterselection\main.cpp 72

:)

so as long as this is an issue, it wasnt the exactly one mentioned here..

Comment: @mikus Well, it *must* return a value because you said so when you stated its type. If you don't want it to return a value, change the return type from `std::string` to `void`.

Comment: @molbdnilo I did change the data type of the function to void.

Comment: @molbdnilo, hah, you don't need to tell me, that's exactly what I explained in my answer and much earlier in the comment :P Im just saying that as long as the above is true, the error was about (no) return value :P

Comment: @mikus Yeah, I didn't look at the name on your comment. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 3):

A declared **std::string** function should return a string and this is not the same as printing it on the screen, use **return "something"** inside the function otherwise declare it **void**.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that the function `CharacterCreation()` (taking no arguments) is never defined, and thus the linker cannot find it.

Try substituting in the following:

> std::string CharacterCreation(int, int);
>
> int main() 
>   {
>       CharacterCreation(1,1); 
>   }

This will call the `CharacterCreation` function you have implemented below the `main` function. Doing this I can compile (and link) your code :)

Comment: Still receiving this error:
Error 1 error C4716: 'CharacterCreation' : must return a value c:\users\jake\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\characterselection\characterselection\main.cpp 72 1 CharacterSelection

Comment: @LilJakers Thats another error. Put a `return` statement returning a `std::string` on the bottom of `CharacterCreation`. Probably its because your compiler settings are more restrictive than they should be, at least according to this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1610030/why-can-you-return-from-a-non-void-function-without-returning-a-value-without-pr).

Answer (score 0):

As I have pointed in my comment before, your CharacterCreation method does not return any value, although you have defined a string as an expected one.

What you most likely want to do is either change CharacterCreation signature to:

```
void CharacterCreation(int RaceChoice, int RaceChoiceLoop)
```

and keep the current implementation

or pack all your console output in a string and return it at the end of the method.

Then in main()

```
string result = CharacterCreation();
```

can retrieve this value and you  can print it in main