# Why is it that any code after the while loop produces no output?

Tags: c

i am learning c language with a book authored by K&R. This code should print a vertical histogram of the lengths of words in its input but outputs nothing. i'm not sure what is really going on.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXWORLD 20 /* Maximum length of a word */
#define MAXNO 20 /* Maximum Number of words in a sentence */

int main(void) {

    int word[MAXNO];
    int i, c, j, nc, nw; /* c: last character input; nc: character counts; nw: word counts */

    for (i = 0; i < MAXNO; ++i)
    {
        word[i] = 0;
    }

    nc = nw = 0;

    while( (c=getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        ++nc;
        if( c ==' ' || c =='\n' || c =='\t')
        {
            /* -1 for excluding the space in the word length */
            word[nw] = nc -1;
            ++nw;
            /* resetting the word-length for the next word */
            nc = 0;
        }
    }

    for( i = MAXWORLD; i >= 1; --i)
    {
        for(j=0;j <= nw;++j)
        {
            if( i <= word[j])
                putchar('*');
            else
                putchar(' ');
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }
}
```

Please, someone should explain.

Comment: It prints output for me.

Comment: note, you're not returning from main (expects an int) that's UB

Comment: @Nate, it's not happening at my end.

Comment: @JHBonarius, I returned 0 from main and nothing changed.

Comment: @JHBonarius: It was in C90, but not in C99 or later. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18402853/must-the-int-main-function-return-a-value-in-all-compilers

Comment: So then the problem is with your environment for compiling and running your code, not with the code itself.  Please tell us about the environment.  What compiler and/or IDE are you using, what commands do you use to compile and run?

Comment: @Nate, I use havard's cs50 ide. If the name of the file is hello.c, I use the command "make hello" without the quotes to compile. The output is stored in a file named hello.

Comment: Ogbonna Stanley, post input (exact keys pressed).  How did you cause an end-of-file?  No evidence that the `while` loop ever completes.

Comment: @Monica, I have been using the wrong keys to cause an EOF. I used ctrl + c instead of ctrl + d. Thanks for pointing that out.